# Rust book listing 10-16: expected type `T` found type `&T`

Tags: rust

I am stuck at [Listing 10-16](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html) when I try to implement the following modification:

> If we change the return type to be `&T` instead of `T` and change the body
>   of the function to return a reference, we wouldn’t need either the
>   `Clone` or `Copy` trait bounds and we wouldn’t be doing any heap
>   allocations. Try implementing these alternate solutions on your own!

My code is

```
use std::cmp::PartialOrd;

fn largest<T: PartialOrd>(list: &[T]) -> &T {
    let mut largest: &T = &list[0];

    for &item in list.iter() {
        if item > largest {
            largest = &item;
        }
    }

    largest
}

fn main() {
    let number_list = vec![34, 50, 25, 100, 65];

    let result = largest(&number_list);
    println!("The largest number is {}", result);

    let char_list = vec!['y', 'm', 'a', 'q'];

    let result = largest(&char_list);
    println!("The largest char is {}", result);
}
```

I get the error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:19
  |
7 |         if item > largest {
  |                   ^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found &T
  |
  = note: expected type `T`
             found type `&T`
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`list.iter()` gives you an iterator over *references* to elements of `list`.

Using the `for &item in ...` syntax, notably the `&item` pattern, you dereference it and use it as a `T`. It might be counter-intuitive at first, but `&item` in this case does the *opposite* of what `&item` would do in most other contexts (e.g. when passing to a function).

However, `largest` is explicitly defined as a `&T`, so in this case the `<` operator tries to compare two different types: `T` and `&T`

Remove the `&` from the pattern and it all works out.

```
for item in list.iter() {
    if item > largest {
        largest = item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that `for &item in …` actually tries to move the value into `item` (because `T` is not `Copy`), which is not allowed since we can't move a borrowed value.  And if we add a `Copy` bound for `T`, we would be allowed to do `for &item in …`, but it would still be useless, since we could not store a reference to `item` in `largest` – since `item` is a copy, it would only live for the loop iteration it was created for.  So `for &item` can never work here.

Comment: @SvenMarnach can you elaborate more?  According to the offical book example 10-15
Using `Copy` does seems to work here.

Comment: @gogoout Take a look at the function prototype in the question. The function is supposed to return a reference to the largest element. That's not possible if you write your loop as `for &item in …`, even with `T: Copy`.